# How to control nodes if DMGR is down in Websphere environment

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

Usually all nodes are managed or administered through DMGR console. 
If the DMGR is down, is there any way to manage the clusters or application servers which are federated to the DMGR?

Answer (score 1):

You can start/stops servers locally using scripts from the `PROFILE\bin` folder or connect using `wsadmin` to nodeagent. Configuration changes are not recommended since they will be overwritten once the `DMGR` is back and you issue synchronization request, as the changes are flowing only from Dmgr to Nodes, not the other way around.

Comment: Is there any specific script to connect to the nodeagent via the wsadmin

Comment: @ronu, no, you just have to provide host and soap port of node agent , instead of default which is  dmgr after federation.